# Islamic views on GENETIC ENGINEERING (ie CRISPER technology for personal gains)

Tags: fiqh, science, baby, ethics

I am currently working on a presentation for my school, tackling the ethical issues with regards CRISPER technology, where one essentially manipulate the genetic code and modify them for children at birth. Such manipulation can be used to irradiate genetic disease or maybe ask for manipulation to get some biological upgrades, such as looks, strength, intelligence, etc. What would the islamic position of such technology?

Comment: Isn't the use of CRISPER Currently highly restricted?  Not many nations allow it for genetic manipulation to proceed to the fetus stage. Rather they are being recommended to use to research for medical needs. Your question may be relevant for perhaps a future time when UN for allows it. Afaik there has been only one "non sanctioned" incident in China to protect the future baby from HIV.

Comment: Well...assuming that gene editing is legal and allowed, for all circumstances. I just want the islamic position.